# How to "focus" on Facebook Comments Plugins' textarea?

Tags: jquery, facebook-comments

I have a button in the html:

```
<a id="comment">Comment</a>
```

When it is clicked I want the browser to focus on Facebook comments' textarea.
I have:

```
$("#comment").click(function() {
        $("#fb-comments textarea").focus();
    });
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's served via an Iframe from Facebook, so you cannot access the content due to the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). (you cannot do this at all)